# C++: vector of generic type to set

Tags: c++, generics, vector, copy, set

How to copy a vector storing shared pointers of the generic type A to the set?

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

template <typename T>
class A {
   public:
      T a;
      A(const T &a_) : a(a_) {}
};

template <typename Type>
class comp
{

   bool operator() (const Type & a1, const const Type &a2) const {
       return (a1->get().a < a2->get().a);
   }
};
```

Unfortunately, this construction does not work

```
int main() {
   using v = std::vector <std::shared_ptr <A <double> >> ;
   using s = std::set <std::shared_ptr <A <double> >,comp <std::shared_ptr <A <double> > > >;

   s.insert(v.begin(), v.end()); //Trying to insert

   return 0;
}
```

and the following error occurs (VS 2015):

```
error C2059: syntax error: '.'
```

Thanks for your help.

**UPDATED SOLUTION:**

Thanks for your comments about using, the updated and working solution is:

```
template <typename T>
class A {
    public:
        T a;
        A(const T &a_) : a(a_) {}
};

template <typename Type>
class comp
{
    public:
    bool operator() (const Type & a1, const const Type &a2) const {
        return (a1.get()->a < a2.get()->a);
    }
};


int main() {
    std::vector <std::shared_ptr <A <double> >> v;
    std::set <std::shared_ptr <A <double> >, comp <std::shared_ptr <A <double> > > > s(v.begin(), v.end());

}
```

Comment: Post compilable code. Post the error messages you are getting.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: @ Neil & Richard: the code has been added....

Comment: `using v` declares a type - it doesn't create an object.

Comment: s is a type, not a set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say something like:

```
using v = std::vector <std::shared_ptr <A <double> >> ;
```

then you create a new type name called `v` which is a vector of whatever.

You can then create objects of that type:

```
v av;      // av is an object of type v
```

and possibly call methods on them:

```
av.begin()
```

should that make sense.

Answer (score 1):

This compiles:

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
class A {
public:
    T a;
    A(const T &a_) : a(a_) {}
};

template <typename Type>
struct comp
{
    bool operator() (Type const &a1, Type const &a2) const
    {
        return (a1.get()->a < a2.get()->a);
    }
};

int main() {

    using v = std::vector <std::shared_ptr <A <double>>>;
    using s = std::set<std::shared_ptr <A <double>>, comp<std::shared_ptr <A <double>>>>;

    v vec;
    s set(vec.begin(), vec.end());

    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/kOPGjt